# Fees for various operation

Tags: protocol, fees, operation

I understand that some operations require a minimal fee, for instance ꜩ0.001271 for transfer operations. Besides, some operations require to burn extra tez. Are these fees documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docs in tezos.git](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html#more-details-on-fees-and-cost-model)

[Docs by TezTech](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md)

To copy from the tezos.git docs:

```
fees >= (minimal_fees + minimal_nanotez_per_byte * size
                      + minimal_nanotez_per_gas_unit * gas)
```

(`size` is the size of the operation in binary.)

With current defaults:

```
minimal_fees = 0.000 1 ꜩ (100 µꜩ)
minimal_nanotez_per_gas_unit = 100 nꜩ/gu (0.000 000 1 ꜩ/gu)
minimal_nanotez_per_byte = 1000 nꜩ/B (0.000 001 ꜩ/B)
```